# Chromium: Anti Ad Plugin(s)/Addon(s)?

Tags: software-recommendation, chromium

I've got Chromium installed from their PPA.  Is there anywhere that various addons or plugins for anti-advertising and similar functionality are listed, so that I can add the addons to my installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Blocking ads

Adblock Plus, of Firefox fame, now has an extension for Chrome: http://adblockplus.org/

However, it took them a long time to start the (still incomplete) project, and [this guy](http://chromeadblock.com) wrote his own extension: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

## Blocking advertisers

A step further is the [Ghostery extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij). It blocks tracker scripts and the like. I use a fairly under-powered laptop to browse the web, and Ghostery cuts page load times in half.

Salon.com runs at least twelve third-party scripts on its front page. Some of them track how you use the site. Salon might use the data to improve the site, or they might sell your browser history to someone else, or both. Others are widgets from social networks like Facebook and Reddit, allowing both easy sharing and easy tracking. The Disqus script handles Salon's comments. On its highest settings, Ghostery blocks it all: trackers, comments, whatever.

AngiesList, on its login page, runs over twelve third-party scripts. Ghostery identifies every single one as an advertiser tracking and selling your browsing information. I forget which, but one of them also handles the actual logging in. On its highest setting, Ghostery prevents logging in to AngiesList. Fortunately, it's easy to disable temporarily. (but I do worry: is angieslist sharing my username and password with other companies??)

[Disconnect.me](https://disconnect.me/) is similar to Ghostery, but is open source.